# How to successfully render an array of images from the Nasa Mars Rover api

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, store, immutable.js

I'm working on a project that consumes data from the Nasa Mars Rover api and keeps it in a store with Immutable.js store. The data is correctly updated in the store, and i'm able to access the data and print it to the console, but i can't get the images to display.

My functions:

```
const renderRoverImages = () => {

    const imageGallery = store.get('roverImages');
    console.log(imageGallery);

    const imageGallerySlice = imageGallery.slice(0, 10);
    console.log(imageGallerySlice);


    // const img_src = imageGallerySlice[8].img_src;
    // console.log(img_src);
    if (imageGallerySlice.hasOwnProperty('img_src')) {
        imageGallerySlice.map(
            image => roverImageGallery(image.get('img_src')).join('')
        );
    }
    return `<p class='loading-images'>Loading Images</p>`;

};


const roverImageGallery = (src) =>
  ` <div class='scroll-item'> <img src='${src}' alt='One of the rover latest images'></div>`;
```

Both the imageGallery and ImageGallerySlice variables print the data i want to the console, but i seem unable to render the images with the logic from there.

[The data printed to my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDIR.png)

I'm able to log images to the console with this variable i commented out above that selects by the array index-

// const img_src = imageGallerySlice[8].img_src;
// console.log(img_src);

Initially throws an error, but then further down the page i'm able to see the image

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FXTP.png)
[Rover Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeZVv.png)

Otherwise without that line no errors appear in the console, but the second conditional statement renders on the page- "images loading"

Many thanks,
Evan

Answer (score 0):

The call to `imageGallerySlice.map` converts one collection into a new collection. However, the result is never used!

Maybe you wanted or even did write something similar to

```
return imageGallerySlice.map(
    image => roverImageGallery(image.get('img_src')).join('')
);
```

This code then brings you to the next issue: An Immutable.js collection's [`.map`](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.0.0/Collection/#map()) does not return an array but a new Immutable.js *collection*.

So you end up with a collection of react components, which React does not understand.

The solution is to explicitly convert to an array, e.g. with [`toArray()`](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.0.0/Collection/#toArray())

```
return imageGallerySlice.toArray().map(
    image => roverImageGallery(image.get('img_src')).join('')
);
```